# How to find a value in tensor from other tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a problem about finding a value in from other tensor.

The description of this problem is as follows.
For example,

```
Input Tensor
s_idx = ( 1, 3, 5, 7)
e_idx = ( 3, 4, 5, 8)


label_s_idx = (2, 2, 3, 6)
label_e_idx = (2, 3, 4, 8)
```

In the figure above, the value of *s_idx[1]* is equal to *label_s_idx[2]* and the value of *e_idx[1]* is equal to *label_e_idx[2]*.

In other words, **the problem is to give *output[i]* a value of 1 if the conditions *s_idx[i] == label_s_idx[i]* and *e_idx[i] == label_s_idx[j]* for some j in range of the length of label_s_idx (== length of label_e_idx) are satisfied.**

Thus, in the above example, the output tensor is

```
output = ( 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

How do I code like this on Tensorflow in Python?

Comment: I suppose combination of `tf.equal` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/equal) and `tf.logical_and` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logical_and) can do this.  But I am confused since you are comparing index 1 and 2 in the example, while you say `s_idx[i] == label_s_idx[i]` when describing the conditions.  More clarifications would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I mean `s_idx[i] == label_s_idx[j] and e_idx[i] == label_e_idx[j]` for some j. So, if `(s_idx[i], e_idx[i]) is contained in [ (label_s_idx[0], label_e_idx[0]), (label_s_idx[1], label_e_idx[1]), ... ,(label_s_idx[x], label_e_idx[x]) ]`, then `output[i]` becomes 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a function designed for this operation. You can implement it using matrix operations as below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

s_idx = [1, 3, 5, 7]
e_idx = [3, 4, 5, 8]
label_s_idx = [2, 2, 3, 6]
label_e_idx = [2, 3, 4, 8]

# convert the variables to one-hot encoding
# s_oh[i,j] = 1 if and only if s_idx[i] == j
# analogous for e_oh
s_depth = tf.reduce_max([s_idx, label_s_idx])
s_oh = tf.one_hot(s_idx, s_depth)
label_s_oh = tf.one_hot(label_s_idx, s_depth)

e_depth = tf.reduce_max([e_idx, label_e_idx])
e_oh = tf.one_hot(e_idx, e_depth)
label_e_oh = tf.one_hot(label_e_idx, e_depth)

# s_mult[i,j] == 1 if and only if s_idx[i] == label_s_idx[j]
# analogous for e_mult
s_mult = tf.matmul(s_oh, label_s_oh, transpose_b=True)
e_mult = tf.matmul(e_oh, label_e_oh, transpose_b=True)

# s_included[i] == 1 if and only if s_idx[i] is included in label_s_idx
# analogous for e_included
s_included = tf.reduce_max(s_mult, axis=1)
e_included = tf.reduce_max(e_mult, axis=1)

# output[i] == 1 if and only if s_idx[i] is included in label_s_idx
# and e_idx[i] is included in label_e_idx
output = tf.multiply(s_included, e_included)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output))
# [0. 1. 0. 0.]
```

Comment: I have one more question, For example

`s_idx = [1, 3, 5, 7]`

`e_idx = [3, 4, 5, 8]`

`label_s_idx = [2, 2, 3, 6]`

`label_e_idx = [2, 3, 4, 8]`

`label_score = [1, 2, 3, 2]`

then, I want to make the output `[0, 3, 0, 0]` by extracting the value of label_score if i is included in label, then output[i] = label_score[j], how can i fix this code for this problem?

Comment: Hmm.  What if there are multiple match?  For example, let `label_s_idx = [2, 2, 3, 3]` and `label_e_idx = [2, 3, 4, 4]`.  Then there will be multiple "j".
By the way, looking back the code, my answer may not align 100% with your intent.  My code finds "i" such that `s_idx[i]` is in `s_label_idx` and `e_idx[i]` is in `e_label_idx`. But do you actually want to require the matched values are found at the same location (same "j")?  If so can you make another example and expected output that clarify your intent?  Then I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. The another problem means when I add other variable `label_score` (its length will be same as length of `label_s_idx` and length of `label_e_idx`). In previous problem, the output means the existance `(s_idx, e_idx)` in `(label_s_idx, label_e_idx)`. But I tray to change the problem a bit differently.

Comment: First, There are no same `(label_s_idx[x], label_e_idx[x])`. So There are no examples such as `label_s_idx = [2, 2, 3, 3]` and `label_e_idx = [2,3,4,4]` because `(label_s_idx[2], label_e_idx[2])` and `(label_s_idx[3], label_e_idx[3])` have same values.

Comment: Also, if there is no `label_score` value to import output, when `(s_idx[i], e_idx[i])` is not contained in `(label_s_idx, label_e_idx)`, then I want to extract 0 for importing output values.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you update the question too?  This will help people to know what problem we talk about.

Comment: Even better would be to open another question, since the changes seem significant.  You can put the link here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I upload new question on this link : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199843/how-to-check-that-the-values-of-tensor-is-contained-in-other-tensor)