# How to check that the values of Tensor is contained in other tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a problem about finding a value from other tensor

It's similar to the following problem : (URL: [How to find a value in tensor from other tensor in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102706/how-to-find-a-value-in-tensor-from-other-tensor-in-tensorflow/52107710?noredirect=1#comment91348123_52107710))

The previous problem was to ask if input tensor **x[i]**, **y[i]** is contained in input tensor **label_x**, **label_y**

Here is an example of the previous problem:

```
Input Tensor
s_idx = (1, 3, 5, 7)
e_idx = (3, 4, 5, 8)

label_s_idx = (2, 2, 3, 6)
label_e_idx = (2, 3, 4, 8)
```

The problem is to give output[i] a value of 1
if **s_idx[i] == label_s_idx[j] and e_idx[i] == label_s_idx[j] for some j** are satisfied for some j.

Thus, in the above example, the output tensor is

```
output = (0, 1, 0, 0)
```

Because (**s_idx[1]** = 3, **e_idx[1]** = 4) is same as (**label_s_idx[2]** = 3, **label_e_idx[2]** = 4)

(s_idx, e_idx) does not have a duplicate value, and (label_s_idx, label_e_idx) does so.

Therefore, it is assumed that the following input example is impossible:

```
s_idx = (2, 2, 3, 3)
e_idx = (2, 3, 3, 3)
```

Because, (**s_idx[2]** = 3, **e_idx[2]** = 3) is same as (**s_idx[3]** = 3, **e_idx[3]** = 3).

What I want to change a bit in this problem is to add another value to the input tensor:

```
Input Tensor
s_idx = (1, 3, 5, 7)
e_idx = (3, 4, 5, 8)

label_s_idx = (2, 2, 3, 6)
label_e_idx = (2, 3, 4, 8)
label_score = (1, 3, 2, 3)
```

*There is no 0 values in label_score tensor

The task in the changed problem is defined as follows:

The problem is to give output_2[i] a value of label_score[j] if **s_idx[i] == label_s_idx[j]** and **e_idx[i] == label_s_idx[j]** for some j are satisfied.

Therefore, the output_2 should be like this:

```
output = (0, 1, 0, 0)  // It is same as previous problem
output_2 = (0, 2, 0, 0)
```

How do I code like this on Tensorflow in Python?

Comment: `label_s_idx = (2, 2, 3, 6)` has duplicate value 2?

Comment: It is possible because `label_e_idx = (2, 3, 4, 8)`, so we can make tuples like that: `(label_s_idx, label_e_idx) = ( (2,2), (2,3), (3,4) ,(6,8) ) `, in this case, there is no duplicate

Comment: Here, `j = 2`, so `output_2` should be (0, 2, 0, 0)`?  Why 3?

Comment: You're right. I will modify the examples of the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf

s_idx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
e_idx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
label_s_idx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
label_e_idx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
label_score = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

# Stack inputs for comparison
se_idx = tf.stack([s_idx, e_idx], axis=1)
label_se_idx = tf.stack([label_s_idx, label_e_idx], axis=1)
# Compare every pair to each other and find matches
cmp = tf.equal(se_idx[:, tf.newaxis, :], label_se_idx[tf.newaxis, :, :])
matches = tf.reduce_all(cmp, axis=2)
# Find the position of the matches
match_pos = tf.argmax(tf.cast(matches, tf.int8), axis=1)
# For those positions where a match was found take the corresponding score
output = tf.where(tf.reduce_any(matches, axis=1),
                  tf.gather(label_score, match_pos),
                  tf.zeros_like(label_score))

# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={s_idx: [1, 3, 5, 7],
                                      e_idx: [3, 4, 5, 8],
                                      label_s_idx: [2, 2, 3, 6],
                                      label_e_idx: [2, 3, 4, 8],
                                      label_score: [1, 3, 2, 3]}))
# >>> [0 2 0 0]
```

It compares every pair of values to each other, so the cost is quadratic on the input size. Also, [`tf.argmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax) is used to find the index of the matching position, and if there is more than one possible index it may return any of them nondeterministically.

Answer (score 1):

This perhaps works.  Since this is a complex task, try more examples and see if expected results are obtained.

```
import tensorflow as tf

s_idx = [1, 3, 5, 7]
e_idx = [3, 4, 5, 8]
label_s_idx = [2, 2, 3, 6]
label_e_idx = [2, 3, 4, 8]
label_score = [1, 3, 2, 3]

# convert to one-hot vector.
# make sure all have the same shape
max_idx = tf.reduce_max([s_idx, label_s_idx, e_idx, label_e_idx])
s_oh = tf.one_hot(s_idx, max_idx)
label_s_oh = tf.one_hot(label_s_idx, max_idx)
e_oh = tf.one_hot(e_idx, max_idx)
label_e_oh = tf.one_hot(label_e_idx, max_idx)

# make a matrix such that (i,j) element equals one if
# idx(i) = label(j)
s_mult = tf.matmul(s_oh, label_s_oh, transpose_b=True)
e_mult = tf.matmul(e_oh, label_e_oh, transpose_b=True)

# find i such that idx(i) = label(j) for s and e, with some j
# there is at most one such j by the uniqueness condition.
output = tf.reduce_max(s_mult * e_mult, axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output))
    # [0. 1. 0. 0.]

# extract the label score at the corresponding j index
# and store in the index i
# then remove redundant dimension
output_2 = tf.matmul(
    s_mult * e_mult, 
    tf.cast(tf.expand_dims(label_score, -1), tf.float32))
output_2 = tf.squeeze(output_2)    

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(output_2))
    # [0. 2. 0. 0.]
```